# print_r($_POST) gives Array()

Tags: php, html, forms

I try to read my POST data:

```
<div id="bestellingklant">
                                    <?php
                                    print_r($_POST);
                                    ?>
                            </div>
```

but the `Print_r` gives: `Array ( )`
while when I inspect the html I get:
`p1:Melk,_vol_0,5l/3/2.40`
so the form data is there.

The data is sent (not?) but I can't read it; My form looks like:

**PHP**

```
<div class="cd-cart">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h2>Winkelkar</h2>
                <span class="undo">Verwijder product. <a href="#0">Ongedaan maken</a></span>
            </header>

            <div class="body">
                <form id="formtosubmit" class="form-style-12" action="checkout.php" method="post">
                    <ul name="products">
                    <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->

                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <a id="checkoutbtn" class="checkout btn" onclick="document.getElementById('formtosubmit').submit()"><em>Ga verder: €<span>0</span></em></a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function addProduct() {
        //var productid = document.getElementById('product').value;
        var product = products[type];
        //this is just a product placeholder
        //you should insert an item with the selected product info
        //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info
        var productAdded = $('<li class="product" name="product' + i + '">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="p' + i + '"value="' + product + "/" + qty + "/" + price + '" />'    +
            '<div class="product-image">' +
            '<a href="image">' +
            '<img src="images/' + product + '.jpg" alt="placeholder"></a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="product-details">' +
            '<a style="color: black;">' + product + '</a>' +
            '<span class="price">€ ' + price + '</span><br>' +
            '<div class="quantity">' +
            '<label>Aantal: ' + qty + '</label> <div class="actions">' +
            ' <a href="#0" class="delete-item" >Delete</a></div></div></div></li>');

        cartList.prepend(productAdded);

    }
```

Comment: where are the form tags and method? you also have what seem to be constants in there or are you using js? the +'s should most likely be dots also to concatenate, hard to say with what you posted.

Comment: have you declare form tag and method?

Comment: ``Array ( )`` simply means ``$_POST`` is empty.

Comment: @Coding update your question with full code, this stuff is not sufficient

Comment: @Fred-ii- the form is build in js yes.

Comment: @Coding you're going to have to update your question with the full code. maybe deceze will reopen and/or others will vote to reopen.

Comment: edited my question